# Tried to build flutter app and got this Error "A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin, dart, visual-studio-code

#### The errors are below

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.10/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar'.
> > repo.maven.apache.org
> Could not download dokka-core-1.4.32.jar (org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-core:1.4.32)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-core/1.4.32/dokka-core-1.4.32.jar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/dokka/dokka-core/1.4.32/dokka-core-1.4.32.jar'.
> > repo.maven.apache.org

#### this is the build.gradle file below

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle- 
    plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your project-level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: That is the exact code in my build.gradle file and its still not working. Everything is upto date. everything is checked when I run flutter doctor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).